# Add whitespace with powershell

Tags: powershell, whitespace

I want to add a whitespace in a text file with powershell between ping and number.

Content text file:

ping192

Thx

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)? Questions that demonstrate your effort to solve the problem are more likely to get answers than ones that just ask for other people to write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show some effort next time, anyway if it's always the same word, like ping which is 4 characters, you can use `string.Insert` method like this:

```
'ping192'.Insert(4,' ')
```

Comment: i want a command in powershell to use Get-Content text file , ang then to add a whitespace after "ping". For example (gc $textfile | % { $_ -replace "ping", "ping +WHITESPACE" | set-content $textfile

Comment: `gc $textfile | % {$_ -replace 'ping','ping '}` ?

Comment: yeah..it's working. I remembered i did this but nothing happend (this is why i ask this question here). But now everything it's ok, my mistake. thx